# Parse Json in flutter with nested objects

Tags: json, flutter

I am currently having issues when trying to print my Varients class (below) I do need to continue to add the nested objects later on but want to address this issue before I do.

So I can return response.body but when I print Varient.fromJson(i).varients I get Failed, no response.

### JSON

```json
{
   "varients":[
      {
         "ProductId":"CMK8866",
         "Colour":"Mid Blue Wash",
         "Sizes":[
            "4",
            "6",
            "8",
            "10",
            "12",
            "14",
            "16"
         ],
         "image":"https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/2/5/2/4/252476b6dcf258958d52438b19b811d76da60dc0_CMK8866_1.jpg?imwidth=120",
         "price":"28.00",
         "name":"Mid Blue Wash Long Leg Straight Jeans",
         "retailer":"prettylittlething"
      },
      {
         "ProductId":"CMG0839",
         "Colour":"Light Blue Wash",
         "Sizes":[
            "4",
            "6",
            "8",
            "10",
            "12",
            "14",
            "16"
         ],
         "image":"https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/f/7/d/f/f7dfd26d523507c2f2e6697e408d932c8e0fac76_cmg0839_1.jpg?imwidth=120",
         "price":"28.00",
         "name":"Light Wash Long Leg Straight Jeans",
         "retailer":"prettylittlething"
      },
      {
         "ProductId":"CMQ3243",
         "Colour":"Off White",
         "Sizes":[
            "4",
            "6",
            "8",
            "10",
            "12",
            "14",
            "16"
         ],
         "image":"https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/d/9/0/2/d902d215e155a61d4cfc8999d714430f5fda01f9_CMK8867_1.jpg?imwidth=120",
         "price":"28.00",
         "name":"Off White Contrast Stitch Long Leg Straight Jeans",
         "retailer":"prettylittlething"
      },
      {
         "ProductId":"CMQ3245",
         "Colour":"Stone",
         "Sizes":[
            "4",
            "6",
            "8",
            "10",
            "12",
            "14",
            "16"
         ],
         "image":"https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/f/f/f/8/fff81a83fae46694dda3fcfef04d28508de64fdc_cmq3243_1.jpg?imwidth=120",
         "price":"22.00",
         "name":"Off White Long Leg Straight Jeans",
         "retailer":"prettylittlething"
      },
      {
         "ProductId":"CMQ3642",
         "Colour":"Ecru",
         "Sizes":[
            "4",
            "6",
            "8",
            "10",
            "12",
            "14",
            "16"
         ],
         "image":"https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/7/7/0/4/77046819c17f097804383b4fda0e0fda56b35239_cmq3245_1.jpg?imwidth=120",
         "price":"28.00",
         "name":"Stone Long Leg Straight Jeans",
         "retailer":"prettylittlething"
      },
      {
         "ProductId":"CMS6181",
         "Colour":"Teal",
         "Sizes":[
            "4",
            "6",
            "8",
            "10",
            "12",
            "14",
            "16"
         ],
         "image":"https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/0/6/0/7/0607455b765c3aed0356be8dafab301182919d2f_cmq3642_1.jpg?imwidth=120",
         "price":"21.00",
         "name":"Ecru With Contrast Stitch Long Leg Straight Jeans",
         "retailer":"prettylittlething"
      },
      {
         "ProductId":"CMS6180",
         "Colour":"Chocolate",
         "Sizes":[
            "4",
            "6",
            "8",
            "10",
            "12",
            "14",
            "16"
         ],
         "image":"https://cdn-img.prettylittlething.com/5/5/9/6/559602e94377d0ebbc5f222b30bbb96ec3104bf8_cms6181_1.jpg?imwidth=120",
         "price":"25.00",
         "name":"Teal Long Leg Straight Jean",
         "retailer":"prettylittlething"
      }
   ]
}
```

### Code

```dart
Future<dynamic> requestProductMonitor() async {
  final product_link = productIDEditingController.text;
  var url = Uri.parse(
      "http://5.226.139.20:8000/getvarient/?url=https://www.prettylittlething.com/mid-blue-wash-long-leg-straight-jeans.html");
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  try {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      print("this is the Json Response $jsonResponse");
      setState(() {
        for (Map<String, dynamic> i in jsonResponse) {
          listModel1.add(Varient.fromJson(i));
          //var test = Varient.fromJson(i).varients;
          //print("This is the varients $test");
          //product_size.add(User.fromJson(i).name);

        }
      });

      showDropDown();
    } else {
      print("Error");
    }
  } catch (exp) {
    print("Failed, no response");
  }
}
```

This is my Varients class:

```dart
List<Varient> modelUserFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Varient>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Varient.fromJson(x)));

String modelUserToJson(List<Varient> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Varient {
  String varients;

  Varient({
    required this.varients,
  });
  factory Varient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Varient(
        varients: json["varients"],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "varients": varients,
      };
}
```

Wondering if anyone has any ideas ?

Comment: Are you facing the error while running web but works for android and windows?

Comment: If you are facing the issue only on the web app, the code is perfectly fine, the API however has an issue which I found out in the console log of chrome dev tools: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://5.226.139.20:8000/getvarient/?url=https://www.prettylittlething.com/mid-blue-wash-long-leg-straight-jeans.html' from origin 'http://localhost:60987' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." This usually happens when the backend of the API has a typo in the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: I'm having issues when running it on the IOS simulator, I haven't tried with any other simulator

Comment: I tried and it works, I will share you the code.

Comment: I have another issue now though, I need to add the response from    List Sizes; to a drop down button but I am getting an error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: For that you have to cast the List<dynamic> to String, I have edited my code to show sizes in a drop down button, you can check out how to cast.

Answer (score 0):

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  dynamic varient;
  requestProductMonitor() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "http://5.226.139.20:8000/getvarient/?url=https://www.prettylittlething.com/mid-blue-wash-long-leg-straight-jeans.html"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      varient = await jsonResponse["varients"];
    } else {
      print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    requestProductMonitor();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: requestProductMonitor(), // async work
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return const Text('Loading....');
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  } else {
                    return GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                                maxCrossAxisExtent: 350,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 10),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: varient.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          List<String> sizes =
                              varient[index]["Sizes"].cast<String>();
                          return Wrap(
                            alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Image.network(
                                varient[index]["image"],
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                              Text(varient[index]["name"]),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  sizes.isEmpty
                                      ? const Text("No Size Available")
                                      : const Text("Available Sizes: "),
                                  sizes.isNotEmpty
                                      ? DropdownButton<String>(
                                          items: sizes.map((String value) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                              value: value,
                                              child: Center(child: Text(value)),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                          onChanged: (_) {},
                                        )
                                      : const SizedBox(),
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        });
                  }
              }
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

This is your desired output, the sizes are now shown in a drop-down menu and can read data from the JSON to get name and image.

Comment: Hi, I have added the changes that you made but now all the app is doing is calling the JSON function and just saying loading where the dropdown should be for the Sizes

Comment: Did you give internet permission in Android Manifest?

Comment: I'm not sure, I was running the app on an IOS simulator too

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data